# Create microsoft graph API subscription to multiple resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I couldn't find a way to create new subscription to multiple resources using the Microsoft graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks

For instance, I would like to create a new subscription to all mailboxes that are related to userPrincipalName that startsWith 'dev': /users/dev1@microsoft.com/messages, /users/dev2@microsoft.com/messages dev1@onmicrosoft.com

Sample request:

*{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "notifurl",
    "resource": "",
    "expirationDateTime":"2018-10-10T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue"
    }*

Can I create it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would need to create a subscription per mailbox. The `resource` parameter does not support wildcards or multiple values.